# drawRect weird behaviour on faster devices

Tags: objective-c, ios, exc-bad-access, drawrect

Ok, I've an array of dummy objects containing property cgpath. This is called darkPathArray property in my UIView.

When I draw them one after another I found an interesting thing to happen. I got EXC_BAD_ACCESS on `CGContextAddPath(context,ppath.path);` (`ppath.path` throws that) when running on iOS 5 sim/device. But When I put a `NSLog` call in front of `CGContextAddPath`, it works correctly. And this is, because it's significantly slown down.

So the problem is in the frequency of `-drawRect` callings. That's ok, I could fake it 'till I'd make it, but that's not the way professional works.

Therefore I'm asking why is this happening?

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)r
{
    // Get the graphics context and clear it
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds);

    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    UIRectFill ([self bounds]);

    // Draw every single section as a path
    for (ShopSection *section in self.shopSectionsArray) {
        // Draw the walls
        [section.darkColor setFill];

        for (MMPath *ppath in section.darkPathArray) {
            CGContextAddPath(context,ppath.path);
            CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
ARC enabled

MMPaths are not changing

EXC_BAD_ACCESS is responding to bad section object / dunno why (they're stored safely in the array)

Superview: UIScrollView
Layer: CATiledLayer

The problem with bad access occurs when the content is rapidly redrawn - on fast device/simulator or when wildly scrolling and zooming.

Edit2:
I think I got it! The problem is that CATiledLayer draws on backround threads, so it somehow catches it's tail. Have anyone an idea how to fix that? What is the best approach for that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are self.shopSectionsArray or section.darkPathArray or any of the `MMPaths` ever being changed during this code? Perhaps in another thread?

Comment: Yes, ARC is enabled. No, MMPaths are not changed in any other code.

Comment: I think I got it. The CATiledLayer is drawing it on different threads. Well, what's the problem with that? Simple drawing doesn't destroy the reference or change anything... does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed my mind and used the CAShapeLayer instead of my MMPath (NSObject with CGPath property). Then using CGRectIntersectsRect, I've managed to get rid of that multithreading bug.
It also mean an optimalization as only the appropriate shapes are drawn in each rect.

So that's how multiple shapes in CATiledLayer shall be drawn:

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
// Get the graphics context and clear it
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds);

[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
UIRectFill ([self bounds]);

// Draw every single section as a path
for (ShopSection *section in self.shopSectionsArray) {

    CAShapeLayer *s = section.wallsShapeLayer;
    // Draw the walls
    if ( CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, s.frame ) )
    {
        // Rasterising before rendering enhances the performance a bit
        s.shouldRasterize = YES;
        [s renderInContext:context];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I also reccomend reading this 
[article](http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/catiledlayer-how-to-use-it-how-it-works-what-it-does/)

Answer (score 1):

This loop is incorrect:

```
for (MMPath *ppath in section.darkPathArray) {
    CGContextAddPath(context,ppath.path);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
}
```

`CGContextAddPath()` adds to "the current path." `CGContextDrawPath` draws "the current path." So you keep extending the path, then redrawing everything. You mean this:

```
for (ShopSection *section in self.shopSectionsArray) {

    // Draw the walls
    [section.darkColor setFill];

    for (MMPath *ppath in section.darkPathArray) {
        CGContextAddPath(context,ppath.path);
    }
}
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
```

Comment: Not quite right. I think you meant to put the CGContextDrawPath at the end of the outermost for block, so it applies to each section (and fills in that color).

Comment: And also, you're still concatenating onto the current path, right? You'd need a `CGContextBeginPath()` at the start of each section to clear the current path.

Comment: The code above does put it outside the outmost for() block. You don't need to call CGContextBeginPath (and shouldn't prior to calling CGContextDrawPath). The main reason to use CGContextBeginPath is if you want to draw the different paths with different styles.

Comment: What I meant was: the original code was attempting to fill each section with a different color. (Assuming that `[section.darkColor setFill]` is setting the fill color on the current context.) Your code does only one fill, so it only fills with one color, whatever the last `section.darkColor` is.

Comment: Fair point and agreed. If you want to change the fill color, you need to draw and then `CGContextBeginPath` to start a new path.

Comment: Thank you both!!! Good advices. However you managed to solve a different problem, that I'm stuck on.
I didn't mention an important thing - the layer of the UIView is a CATiled layer. The problem obviously occures when I'm both zooming and scrolling in the scrollView (a superview), so when the content is rerendering quickly. The bad access is in the section object, that is stored in an array. I have no idea what goes wrong with that during the time.

Comment: CATiled layers can call back on multiple threads. Mutable array writes are not thread-safe.

Comment: Yes. That's a clue. Well I actually don't write to that array (I'm using it in only this piece of code), but I have to change it somehow, otherwise it'd work.. Am I right?

Comment: I'd have to see a lot more of the design to advise on that. It depends on how you're doing things, and on how it's crashing.